# Access Filters not working with ADODB.Recordset connection err(Data Provider could not be initialized

Tags: mysql, vba, ms-access, odbc

We have migrated part of our Access database to mysql, this snippet simply retrieves the sql statement from a table containing form names and sql statements and then sets it as the forms recordset

The issue i have right now is although the speed is a tremendous improvement, The access front end is not completely functioning as expected right now, the Refresh and filter by text access functions do not work, simply throw error (Data Provider could not be initialized).

I believe this has something to do with us setting the recordsource to the form, is there anyway around this without a huge performance drop?

If i simply link a view from mysql into access and set the forms recordsource as that view, it takes a much longer time to load and filter

The Picture here [http://puu.sh/BXw55/fe8b01d8d0.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbAxh.png) Shows when the error occurs, when trying to use Access Filters

Here is the function:

```
Private Sub Command91_Click() 'Clear filters'
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
Dim oConn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim ConnStr As String
Dim strOrderBy As String

'Creating new connection, and then using ConnectString function to connect to mysql Database'
Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection
oConn.Open ConnectString

'Clears filter fields to null'
fltrDocBaseID.Value = Null
fltrDocBaseClientDocNumber.Value = Null
fltrDisciplinesID.Value = Null
fltrDocTypeID.Value = Null
fltrDocSubTypesID.Value = Null
fltrProjectID.Value = Null
FilterOn = False
fltrDocBaseTitle1.Value = Null
fltrDocBaseTitle2.Value = Null
fltrDocBaseTitle3.Value = Null
fltrDocBaseTitle4.Value = Null

'Retrieves SQL code from refreshDS(fname As String) located in Module- SQLDatasources'
strSQL = refreshRS(Me.Name)
'Creates new recordset'

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
'Connects to mysql database, runs strSQL and then sets page recordset'
'to the current strSQL'
With rs
    Set .ActiveConnection = oConn
    .Source = strSQL
    .LockType = adLockOptimistic
    .CursorType = adOpenKeyset
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .Open
End With

Set Me.Recordset = rs
'Closes recordset and connections, This is a good practice for traffic efficiency'
rs.Close
oConn.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set oConn = Nothing
```

Comment: I think the issue would be revealed in your connection string. What data provider/driver to you reference in the connection string? Are you sure you have that provider/driver installed?

Comment: @ArcherBird
Using odbc 5.1 driver, as the newer drivers had a bug of #Deleted for medium/long texts
The connection string simply calls a file dsn which is on a secure location


Public Function ConnectString() 'Global mysql connection'

ConnectString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};PORT=XXXX;DATABASE={IMS-DATA};SERVER=192.XXX.XX.39;FILEDSN=\\RJEDB01\IMSConnections\IMS-DATA.dsn;UID=****;PWD=****"

End Function

Comment: which line of code throws the error?

Comment: the other thing to look at would be whatever gets assigned into your strSQL variable (looks like this is being set by some function, `RefreshRS` not shown here). You would want to check for differences in the grammer between JET SQL and MySQL

Comment: you should probably use linked tables